# List Hive table properties to create another table

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table on Hive already created. Is there a way to copy the table schema to a terminal to pass it to a create table on another Hive server?

Comment: If you have to only copy the table structure, you can use `create table ... like` construct.

Comment: The problem with the `LIKE` is that they're in two different servers with two different Hive servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` command? I think it should give you the create ddl you are looking for.

This [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-967) provides some background on when this was implemented.

Comment: It was a matter of removing the comments and adjusting a few parameters and it worked. Thanks.